# Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `tag` supplied to `NavLink`

Tags: reactjs, web-components-shards

I'm currently trying to integrate a shard-dashboard into my react app. Everything works pretty well, except that the search-navbar is scaled way too big. The console gives me the following error:

> "Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `tag` supplied to `NavLink`. in NavLink (at SidebarNavItem.js:8)".

The mentioned file looks as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { NavLink as RouteNavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { NavItem, NavLink } from "shards-react";

const SidebarNavItem = ({ item }) => (
  <NavItem>
    <NavLink tag={RouteNavLink} to={item.to}>
      {item.htmlBefore && (
        <div
          className="d-inline-block item-icon-wrapper"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.htmlBefore }}
        />
      )}
      {item.title && <span>{item.title}</span>}
      {item.htmlAfter && (
        <div
          className="d-inline-block item-icon-wrapper"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.htmlAfter }}
        />
      )}
    </NavLink>
  </NavItem>
);

SidebarNavItem.propTypes = {
  /**
   * The item object.
   */
  item: PropTypes.object
};

export default SidebarNavItem;
```

I've already googled this up a lot, but all related errors I've found were caused by some components which are not part of my code.

Comment: well you cant use `tag` as a prop in `NavLink` it's saying so you'll need to change that

Comment: why did you think you could use it?

Comment: Because this code works in another Project. @RedBaron

Comment: it doesn't look like it's a prop that exists. cant see it anywhere in the docs. are you able to pass it to another prop?

Comment: What do you mean by passing it to another prop?

Comment: well according to the docs I can't see `tag` as a prop anywhere on `NavLink` so if you check the docs here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink, is there any one of those you could use instead as it doesn't know what `tag` is. and im not sure how that other code is working

Comment: oh wait, ignore that, im reading the wrong thing

Comment: can you tell me what this is? `RouteNavLink` (in your code)

Comment: and are you using the latest version?

Comment: The thing is that it works in another Project from which I'm trying to integrate it into my Project, so I think the tag prop should somehow be valid. Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: yeh it should be valid I was looking at the wrong docs :D

Comment: are you on the latest version of shards-react? or the same version as that project?

Comment: Yes I'm at the same version as the project.

Comment: and what is this? `RouteNavLink` ?

Comment: The NavLink of the router dom.

Comment: yeh but what is it? string, object, function?

Comment: and I mean in your code, can you `console.log()` it

Comment: console.log said its an [object Object]

Comment: posted an answer but feel free to keep chatting underneath that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your issue is that it expect `Func | String` but you're getting an `[object Object]` so you'll need to figure that out why the type is wrong

Comment: Thanks to your help I was able to fix it. :) The problem was that I've exported my routes the wrong way. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly the same problem, using the same framework.

The problem is this line:

```
import { NavLink as RouteNavLink } from "react-router-dom";
```

It seems this import syntax transforms the `Component` (function) into a reference, which is why you obtain an `Object` when logging into the console. The `tag` property is then wrong-typed.

A basic work-around that solves the problem:

```
<NavLink tag={(props) => <RouteNavLink {...props} />} to={item.to}>
```